# Is any way to change color of view titles in a Panel in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

What key among [this ones](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color) can change the appearance of these view titles in the Panel in VSCode?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can change the color of tabs in VSCode by modifying the "workbench.colorCustomizations" setting in your user settings file. Here's how:

1. Open VSCode and go to File > Preferences > Settings (or press Ctrl + , on Windows or Cmd + , on Mac).
2. In the search bar at the top, type `workbench.colorCustomizations` and press Enter
3. In the `settings.json` file, add the following code:

```json
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
        "tab.activeBackground": "#yourColorCode",
        "tab.inactiveBackground": "#yourColorCode"
}
```

Replace `yourColorCode` with the hex code or name of the color you want to use for the active and inactive tabs
Save the file and the changes should take effect immediately

Comment: make the modification theme specific

Comment: unfortunantly, this settings change th tabs of editor, but not tabs for termital, output, etc